# Why are objects along a curve using the Array modifier oriented incorrectly?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to create an arch that should be made of a set of circles around a NURBS curve. First of all I switch to front view, and create a NURBS curve with the shape of the arch that I want to create. Then I add a circle right in the last point of the NURBS curve. Then I add an array and a curve modifier to the circle:

[image]

But unfortunately, this is the result:

[image]

The problem is in the way that the circle gets replicated: it should keep its center around the NURBS curve, so that I obtain a set of circles around the curve than can then be united to have an arch. How do I specify that?

Comment: Ramy, posting a copy of your ~.blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) would be extremely helpful in answering your quesion.

Comment: That's the result you should get. You're not using the proper method to create your arch. Instead of 2 dimensional circles, use cylinders.